# Could not operate datetime.timedelta(0, 3600) with block values must be str, not datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here I have a dataset with date, time and one input. Here I want to add timedelta for specific time and adding to the datetime column.

So here first I convert the specify time into 00:00:00 and it will be the start time. from that time I want to add one hour , one hour till to range of 6. and then I want to add it into the datetime column.

I wrote the code but it gave me error : `Could not operate datetime.timedelta(0, 3600) with block values must be str, not datetime.timedelta`

My code is :

```
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = data['X3'].eq(5)
data['duration'] = data['date_time'].mask(mask, data['date_time'].dt.floor('d'))

T= pd.DataFrame({"data['duration']":[ "00:00:00" for i in range(3) ]},index=np.random.randint(0,100,3))
for it in range(1,4):
 Time = T +timedelta(hours=1*it)
```

Got error:

```html
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1466         try:
-> 1467             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
   1468         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    204     if use_numexpr:
--> 205         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    206     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
    119     if result is None:
--> 120         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    121 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
     64     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
---> 65         return op(a, b)
     66 

TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in eval(self, func, other, errors, try_cast, mgr)
   1414             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1415                 result = get_result(other)
   1416 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get_result(other)
   1382             else:
-> 1383                 result = func(values, other)
   1384 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1494                     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1495                         result[mask] = op(xrav, y)
   1496             else:

TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-771f9e94063d> in <module>()
     13 T= pd.DataFrame({"data['duration']":[ "00:00:00" for i in range(3) ]},index=np.random.randint(0,100,3))
     14 for it in range(1,7):
---> 15     Time = T +timedelta(hours=1*it)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
   1527                 self = self.fillna(fill_value)
   1528 
-> 1529             return self._combine_const(other, na_op, try_cast=True)
   1530 
   1531     f.__name__ = op_name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _combine_const(self, other, func, errors, try_cast)
   4774         new_data = self._data.eval(func=func, other=other,
   4775                                    errors=errors,
-> 4776                                    try_cast=try_cast)
   4777         return self._constructor(new_data)
   4778 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in eval(self, **kwargs)
   3685 
   3686     def eval(self, **kwargs):
-> 3687         return self.apply('eval', **kwargs)
   3688 
   3689     def quantile(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
   3579 
   3580             kwargs['mgr'] = self
-> 3581             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   3582             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
   3583 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in eval(self, func, other, errors, try_cast, mgr)
   1420             raise
   1421         except Exception as detail:
-> 1422             result = handle_error()
   1423 
   1424         # technically a broadcast error in numpy can 'work' by returning a

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in handle_error()
   1403                 raise TypeError(
   1404                     'Could not operate {other!r} with block values '
-> 1405                     '{detail!s}'.format(other=other, detail=detail))  # noqa
   1406             else:
   1407                 # return the values

TypeError: Could not operate datetime.timedelta(0, 3600) with block values must be str, not datetime.timedelta
```

What I expected output is:

```html
date time        x3  expected output           x3       (add) timedelta 
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7 10/3/2018 6:15:00   
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5 10/3/2018 6:45:00      5         0:00:00 
10/3/2018 7:45:00  7 10/3/2018 7:45:00                1:00:00 
10/3/2018 9:00:00  7 10/3/2018 8:45:00                2:00:00 
10/3/2018 9:25:00  7 10/3/2018 9:30:00    second 5            0:00:00
10/3/2018 9:30:00  5 10/3/2018 9:45:00                3:00:00 
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7 10/3/2018 10:30:00                     1:00:00
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7 10/3/2018 10:45:00                     2:00:00
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7 10/3/2018 10:45:00              4:00:00 
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5 10/3/2018 11:30:00                     3:00:00
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7 10/3/2018 12:30:00                     4:00:00
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7    
10/3/2018 16:25:00 7    
10/3/2018 18:00:00 5    
10/3/2018 19:00:00 7    
10/3/2018 19:30:00 7
```

My csv file :
[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

So here I want increase the length of my data with adding this time delta .
Can anyone help me to solve this error?

```html
For the reference

expected output           x3       (add) timedelta 
 10/3/2018 6:15:00   
 10/3/2018 6:45:00      5               0:00:00 
 10/3/2018 7:45:00                1:00:00 
 10/3/2018 8:45:00                2:00:00 
 10/3/2018 9:30:00    second 5                    0:00:00
 10/3/2018 9:45:00                3:00:00 
 10/3/2018 10:30:00                     1:00:00
 10/3/2018 10:45:00                     2:00:00
 10/3/2018 10:45:00              4:00:00 
 10/3/2018 11:30:00                     3:00:00
 10/3/2018 12:30:00                     4:00:00
    

Here you can till to 10:45:00 I need to give time range (4) after starting the new time also
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to create solution with no loop:

```
#datetime column
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
#set starts 00:00:00
mask = data['x3'].eq(5)
data['duration'] = data['date_time'].mask(mask, data['date_time'].dt.floor('d'))

#create helper group column
m = mask.cumsum()
#create counter per groups, but first group (values before first 5) are set to 0
data['g'] = data[m != 0].groupby(m).cumcount()
#all values > 5 aare set to 0, not > 6 because python counts from 0
data['g'] = data['g'].fillna(0).mask(data['g'] > 5, 0)
#get values of date_time only for 5 and forward filling it
first = data.loc[mask, 'date_time'].reindex(data.index, method='ffill')
#converting hours to timedeltas and add to duration column
data['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['g'], unit='h') + first
```

---

```
print (data)
         date      time  x3           date_time            duration    g
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   7 2018-03-10 06:15:00                 NaT  0.0
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 2018-03-10 06:45:00 2018-03-10 06:45:00  0.0
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   7 2018-03-10 07:45:00 2018-03-10 07:45:00  1.0
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   7 2018-03-10 09:00:00 2018-03-10 08:45:00  2.0
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   7 2018-03-10 09:25:00 2018-03-10 09:45:00  3.0
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   5 2018-03-10 09:30:00 2018-03-10 09:30:00  0.0
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   7 2018-03-10 11:00:00 2018-03-10 10:30:00  1.0
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   7 2018-03-10 11:30:00 2018-03-10 11:30:00  2.0
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   7 2018-03-10 13:30:00 2018-03-10 12:30:00  3.0
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 2018-03-10 13:50:00 2018-03-10 13:50:00  0.0
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   7 2018-03-10 15:00:00 2018-03-10 14:50:00  1.0
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   7 2018-03-10 15:25:00 2018-03-10 15:50:00  2.0
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   7 2018-03-10 16:25:00 2018-03-10 16:50:00  3.0
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   5 2018-03-10 18:00:00 2018-03-10 18:00:00  0.0
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   7 2018-03-10 19:00:00 2018-03-10 19:00:00  1.0
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   7 2018-03-10 19:30:00 2018-03-10 20:00:00  2.0
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   7 2018-03-10 20:00:00 2018-03-10 21:00:00  3.0
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   7 2018-03-10 22:05:00 2018-03-10 22:00:00  4.0
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5 2018-03-10 22:15:00 2018-03-10 22:15:00  0.0
19  10/3/2018  23:40:00   7 2018-03-10 23:40:00 2018-03-10 23:15:00  1.0
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5 2018-04-10 06:58:00 2018-04-10 06:58:00  0.0
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   7 2018-04-10 13:00:00 2018-04-10 07:58:00  1.0
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   7 2018-04-10 16:00:00 2018-04-10 08:58:00  2.0
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   7 2018-04-10 17:00:00 2018-04-10 09:58:00  3.0
24  10/4/2018  18:00:00   7 2018-04-10 18:00:00 2018-04-10 10:58:00  4.0
25  10/5/2018   7:00:00   7 2018-05-10 07:00:00 2018-04-10 11:58:00  5.0
26  10/5/2018   8:00:00   7 2018-05-10 08:00:00 2018-04-10 06:58:00  0.0
27  10/5/2018   9:00:00   7 2018-05-10 09:00:00 2018-04-10 06:58:00  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. But I have a doubt in your answer. In duration column first 5 start time is 6:45:00 after one hour time should be 07:45:00. But in your answer it came 8:45:00, then the time duration is 2 hrs.  So how to change that ?

Comment: @team - Can you check now? Not 100% sure if understand.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's 90% corrected as I am seen your code . But one issue is there , now just think first start time is  6:45:00 . From that Time I need time range till to 4 hours. But here only 3 hrs, mean till to 9:45:00 came after that 10:45:00 didn't display. so then how to code to show that time range?

Comment: @team - not understand :(

Comment: @ jezrael here first input of 5 time is 6:45:00 So I need to add 4 hours more from the start time. But inbetween that time period second input will be there and then start time will become 0 . Then first input four hour range will be not there. I posted the image of that what I am trying to say you may can look at it?

Comment: @team - sure, thank you. Btw, why is necessary add 4 hours?

Comment: @ jezrael I want to add summation equation with the range of 4 hours . That's why I am looking forward this answer. Here I posted the image for your refer

Comment: @team - So for timestamps under `00:00:00` in `4` hours, so  for first group `2018-03-10 06:45:00` and `2018-03-10 10:45:00` need to add 1 hour? I need explain it more.

Comment: yes exactly. Then second group is 9:30:00 to 13:30:00.